# Laravel | Using Eloquent hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-many-through, laravel-5.5

I have a table called `invoiceDetails` that has `item_id` as `foreign key` from another table called `items` which has `category_id` as `foreign key` from table called `categories`.

I want to do that following using eloquent:

```
$result = InvoiceDetail::groupBy('item_id')
                ->selectRaw('sum(qty) as qty, item_id')->with('item', 'category')->get();
```

but I am getting error:

```
Call to undefined relationship [category] on model [App\InvoiceDetail].
```

Here's my relation inside `Category` model:

```
public function invoiceDetail() {
       return $this->hasManyThrough('App\InvoiceDetail', 'App\Item', 'category_id', 'item_id');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try adding 'id', 'id' at last as mentioned in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). And yes This method should be written in InvoiceDetail model. Not in category model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you would even need a `hasManyThrough` relation here, unless you want to fetch all `InvoiceDatail` objects belonging to all items which in turn belong to the Category. That part is not clear from your question.

But in your example you are fetching items with their category from distinct item_id.

The reason this is not working is because you are trying to fetch the category relation from the `InvoiceDetail` object, which does not exist.

```
->with('item', 'category')
```

You want to load the `Category` based on the item relation, not based on the `InvoiceDetail`, try the dot notation (given that you did define the other relations)

```
->with('item.category')
```

Relations should be like this:

```
class InvoiceDetail extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Item::class);
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    public function invoiceDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\InvoiceDetail::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Item::class);
    }


    public function invoiceDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(\App\InvoiceDetail::class, \App\Item::class, 'category_id', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

You would want to use the `hasManyThrough` if, for example, you have a Category and you want to load all the InvoiceDetails directly.

```
dd($category->invoiceDetails);
```

Comment: Great answer, the dot notation worked. Could you please clarify the usage of ‘hasManyThrough’ as I didn’t find any useful reference out there?

Comment: @CairoCoder The documentation actually has a pretty good example included, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: No there's not, it follows the path of the hasMany's :)